# python matplotlib barh reduce gap between bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a `barh` bar chart with two bars only in the figure, but when plotting them, they are very far apart:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ('Out', 'In')
bar_values = [5, 10]
num_items = len(labels)
width = 0.25
ind = np.arange(num_items)
bar_width = 0.1

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

barlist = ax.barh(ind,
                bar_values,
                bar_width,
                align='edge',
                color='green')

barlist[0].set_color('mediumseagreen')
barlist[1].set_color('orangered')

ax.set_yticks(ind)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Total')

plt.show()
```

Is there a way of putting the bars closer together? I have already tried to specify the size of the figure, but that only reduces the overall size and has no impact on the gap size...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either just increase the width of the bars by setting `bar_width = 0.6` or a similar value, or you could reduce the y range of the figure, for example:

```
barlist = ax.barh([0.1, 0.3],
                bar_values,
                bar_width,
                align='edge',
                color='green')
ax.set_yticks([0.1, 0.3])
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
```

Both should increase the width of the bars compared to the distance between the bars. 
[image: Reduced y range]